# Python error code: unexpected character

Tags: python

Can anyone help me figure out why I keep getting the error "unexpected character after line continuation character" with this line of code...

```
r=spi.xfer2([4\2\(channel>>2),(channel&3)<<6,0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend the backslashes to accomplish?

Comment: The \ is interpreted as a "line continuation character" and can be used to split up overly long lines, hence, nothing should come after it. Did you mean / instead?

Comment: i believe I figured it out, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
r=spi.xfer2([4\2\(channel>>2),(channel&3)<<6,0])
```

isn't valid Python. The Python interpreter thinks the first `\` character is a line continuation character and it should not have anything after it except a newline.

If you are using `\` to mean integer division (a la VB) then you need to change it to the Python equivalent, `//`.

```
r=spi.xfer2([4 // 2 // (channel >> 2),(channel & 3) << 6,0])
```

If not, then I think you need to explain what this code is supposed to do.